# Find value in multiple log files and generate information in a single output file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with several .log files, of two different types, inside it. Near the end of each log file, there is a line with the following information:
  `I:         -11.4`, before the "I:" there are 2 blanks and after there are 10 blanks. What I'm trying to generate is a single .txt file, named from the
log file only with values below -11.9, eg:

valuelogs.txt

```
namefile.log -12.0
namefile.log -12.5
namefile.log -13.0
namefile.log -14.0
```

I'm trying to use the commands I found in the links:
[docs.microsoft\select-string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2)

[superuser.com/questions/1589183/powershell-command-to-find-string-in-a-text-file](https://superuser.com/questions/1589183/powershell-command-to-find-string-in-a-text-file-then-extract-that-line-and-prev)

[extract-specific-text-from-multiple](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2080658-extract-specific-text-from-multiple-text-files-to-csv)

Command:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Logs\*.log" | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory" } | ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "I:") {
 New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
 Value = $A} | Out-File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\valuelogs.log" -Append
 }
}
```

but it doesn't generate the output file with the information I need.

**EDITED**:
Below is the content of the file:

Note: the intended value is the final one, below the line "Integrated loudness:", which would be the average of all values of I: that exist in each row.

File content:

```
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.4      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -49.8 S: -26.7     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.5      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -50.9 S: -27.1     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.6      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -51.6 S: -27.3     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.7      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -53.0 S: -27.4     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.8      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -53.6 S: -27.5     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 198.9      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -58.6 S: -28.3     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 199        TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -61.8 S: -28.9     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 199.1      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -65.0 S: -31.2     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 000001e14c3b09c0] t: 199.2      TARGET:-23 LUFS    M: -68.1 S: -31.9     I: -11.4 LUFS       LRA:   2.4 LU
   Integrated loudness:
    I:         -11.4 LUFS
    Threshold: -21.5 LUFS
```

Second log file contents:

Note that in this log the value I want is in front of `Input Integrated:`

```
size=N/A time=00:02:36.90 bitrate=N/A speed=26.1x    
size=N/A time=00:02:50.00 bitrate=N/A speed=26.1x    
size=N/A time=00:03:03.20 bitrate=N/A speed=26.1x    
size=N/A time=00:03:16.50 bitrate=N/A speed=26.1x    
size=N/A time=00:03:29.90 bitrate=N/A speed=26.2x    
size=N/A time=00:03:33.26 bitrate=N/A speed=26.3x    
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 00000193badb3000] 
Input Integrated:     -7.2 LUFS
Input True Peak:      +1.5 dBTP
Input LRA:             3.5 LU
Input Threshold:     -17.4 LUFS
```

Comment: at what point in the process you have created do you NOT get what you need?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I left only the command that at least generated the output, but without information.

Comment: where does the `$A` come from? you need to post a minimal _working_ code sample ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I used like this the command, I thought $A was a variable being defined to get a value! I took the command and just changed the folder path on my computer.

Comment: until you post valid code ... no one can accurately tell where the errors may be. [*grin*] including undefined $Vars in code will not work ... and that may be where your error is ... you are creating a property with nothing in it.

Comment: @Lee_Daileyr You are indeed right about the definition of the undefined variable. I'm still learning the PS and I interpreted the command wrong. The answer in the post solved the problem satisfactorily, thanks.

Comment: you are welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... and that you got things working as needed. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$logMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Logs\*.log" -Pattern '(?<I>^ +I:) +(?<Number>.+)|(?<I>^Input Integrated:) +(?<Number>.+)' -List | Select-Object -Property FileName -ExpandProperty Matches
    $results = foreach ($log in $logMatches) {
        $number = $log.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Number" }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FileName = $log.Filename
            Number = [decimal]$($number.Value -replace " .*")
        }
    }
    $results | Where-Object { $_.Number -lt -11.9 } | Out-File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\valuelogs.log"
```

Comment: I put the contents of the file in the post to make it easier for what I'm trying to get from the file. I'm sure your command didn't work because I lacked a better explanation on my part.

Comment: When I run your command, it showed the following error:
```Unable to convert value "-70.0        LRA:   0.0 LU" for the type "System.Decimal". Error: "The input string was not in a correct format."```

Comment: @Clamarc Thanks for posting the file content. I've updated the pattern match to accommodate for the extra `I:'s`.

Comment: it found the desired value, but it showed an error message of conversion to decimal and did not generate the file, see error below:

```Unable to convert value "-11.4 LUFS" to type "System.Decimal". Error: "The input string was not in a correct format."```

Comment: despite you being explicitly declaring the new type of the variable $number, the shell keeps showing error of conversion to decimal?... this was not supposed to be happening!

Comment: @Clamarc I see you've updated the file content again, as the code is doing a text pattern match any changes have the potential to break it. I've updated with a `-replace` as a fix for the latest version.

Comment: is that I created a test file. As I'm in the learning phase, I'm trying to find the problem too, so I study more and learn more!... your change worked, it's OK. Very thanks.

Comment: a question, how to make this script run anywhere and any folder on my PC? I changed the path to %username% and it shows path error!

Comment: @Clamarc Please open a new question rather than append to this one, it's the fastest way to get an answer.

Comment: I'll open it now, thanks.

Comment: I opened the other question as you suggested, the title is: Run powershell script from anywhere in the PC. thanks.

Comment: The LUFS normalization filter I use generates two logs with different endings, I already knew that!, but I wanted to try to change your script myself, to learn more and also be able to use your script in the second log.
I did several tests changing the pattern, but without success, so I put the content of the second log in my post, which you replied, for your help again!... so I would have two scripts for my two logs! thanks again.

Comment: @Clamarc I've extended the Regex pattern to match the new requirement.

Comment: during this morning I managed, after several attempts, to correctly change the pattern and create the "other script"... only your change was much better because you did everything in one script! thank's boy!